# I need to insert into 1 of 4 possible columns based off where the variable is

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, string, insert

So I have a fantasy draft like system where the user can draft 4 players, I need to send scores based off stats. In the page where I enter the stats and output them I realized I can not insert to one column because the column can change based off of what order that player was drafted. For example, player A can be in the database under the columns `draftedPlayer1`, `draftedPlayer2`, `draftedPlayer3`, or `draftedPlayer4`. This is the SQL string I wrote to see if it would work, but its not working. If anyone knows whats wrong with my string or a better solution that would be great. For reference, Selectedplayer is the player that the stats will be going to and totalFP are the fantasy points that player generated.

```
 string SQLtotal1 = 
        "INSERT INTO Drafted_Table WHEN draftedPlayer1 = '"+selectedPlayer1
        +"' THEN player1FP ='"+totalscore+ "' WHEN draftedPlayer2 = '" 
        + selectedPlayer1 + "' THEN player2FP ='" + totalscore 
        + "' WHEN draftedPlayer3 = '" + selectedPlayer1 + "' THEN player3FP ='" 
        + totalscore + "' WHEN draftedPlayer4 = '" + selectedPlayer1 
        + "' THEN player4FP ='" + totalscore + "'";
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CASE` before indicating your `WHEN` statements

Comment: I added a CASE to each when and it says incorrect syntax near the keyword CASE

Comment: you only need 1 CASE. check the syntax https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms181765(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: You cannot use case in insert statement for determining which column to insert

Answer (score 0):

Its probably better to do the logic check earlier in the code like this.
Declare two variables for columnNames

```
var playerPosition;
var scorePosition;
```

use simple c# if else statement to assign

columnNames to draftPlayer1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and then to player1FP or 2 or 3 or 4 based on value of selectedPlayer1

Then use your insert statement like this...

```
string SQLtotal1 = "INSERT INTO Drafted_Table(" + playerPosition + "," + scorePosition+") values('"+selectedPlayer1+"'," + totalScore + "')";
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, I will need to see how to implement it though. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any a sample code for what the if statements would be, ive tried a few but nothing works.